# Exception: Inconsistent java and sql object types

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

There are types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_type IS OBJECT (
  id VARCHAR2(20),
  name VARCHAR2(40),
  phone NUMBER
);
```

I'm trying to create objects using these types:

```
....
Object[] myArray = new Object[3];
Object[] struct = new Object[values.size()];

int arrayIndex = 0;
for (User user : values) {
    myArray[0] = user.id().toString();
    myArray[1] = user.getName().toString();
    myArray[2] = user.getPhone();

    struct[arrayIndex++] = con.createStruct("my_type",myArray);
}
```

On the line with the creation of the structure of con.createStruct, an error occurs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Inconsistent java and sql object types, for classes implementing ORAData or OracleData, respective factory classes ORADataFactory and OracleDataFactory should be registered in typeMap.
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   myArray[0] = user.id().toString();
   myArray[1] = user.getName().toString();
   myArray[2] = user.getPhone();
```

This should be like:

```
-- First element of the array.
    myArray[0].id  = user.id().toString();
    myArray[0].name  = user.getName().toString();
    myArray[0].phone  = user.getPhone();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could employ class `StructDescriptor` from Oracle JDBC extensions:

```
StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("my_type",conn);
Object[] attributes = {user.id().toString(),
               user.getName().toString(),
               user.getPhone()};

new STRUCT(structDescriptor, connection, attributes);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/StructDescriptor.html

Comment: `oracle.sql.ARRAY/ArrayDescriptor/STRUCT/StructDescriptor/..` depricated:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/deprecated-list.html